# styling node label not working in d3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created the force directed graph with label on node. But somehow, the styling for the label not working and I am not sure what is overwriting this... here is my code snippet:

```
  node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(graph.nodes, function(d){return d.id})
      .enter().append("g")
      .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended))
  node.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .attr('r', function(d){
      return forceProperties.collide.radius;
    });

  node.append('text')
    .text(function(d) {return d.id})
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
        .style("fill", "#555") // these styles doesn't work
        .style("font-family", "Arial")
        .style("font-size", 12)
```

Here is my plunkr which has this problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/WJWZ6p7yBhNI6O1AqPby?p=preview

Please let me know if you need any more info on this.

Comment: you search for `g.node` but you never create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is filled grey (#555) but in your `updateDisplay()` function you appear to be adding a red (or blue) stroke to your text nodes which hides the fill.

If you don't want a stroke on your text you can give it a `stroke-width` of `0` like so.

```
node.append('text')
  .text(function(d) {return d.id})
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style("fill", "#555555")
    .style("font-family", "Arial")
    .style("font-size", 12)
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0SFW9A0X4O2wJKkk6pQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @ksav .. you saved my day

Comment: No probs @kaounKaoun